# Spring REST service is returning json as expected, but I get asked to download it rather than the browser displaying it

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I followed the following tutorial :

http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/

It is a small guide on creating a hypermedia driver REST service using Spring.

I completed the tutorial, and ran the resulting application up successfully. However, When I hit my controller, the browser asks me to download or open the file, rather than just displaying it in the browser.

Any ideas?

EDIT : Adding controller code :

```
package testingRest;

import org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Greeting extends ResourceSupport
{
    private final String content;

    @JsonCreator
    public Greeting(@JsonProperty("content") String content)
    {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContent()
    {
        return content;
    }
}
```

Response I get back :

```
{"content":"Hello, world!","_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=world"}}}
```

Comment: can you post your controller code? Are your responding with plain json response or invoking a web page?

Comment: Added Controller code

Comment: Can you also add the content-type of the HTTP response? If you use a REST client such as https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/ to do the request, you can see all response headers.

Comment: The response I get from it is : 

{"content":"Hello, world!","_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=world"}}}

Comment: You didn't actually add your controller, which is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using just JSON String, then you need to set the HTTP Header Content-Type as `application/json`.

So in your controller, you need to have the following to set the content type

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```

Comment: This really shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @chrylis care to explain?

Comment: Returning a `String` as `@ResponseBody` should Just Work, and you should *never* manually twiddle the content-type like this in a Spring MVC controller; you should use the annotations if you really need to specify it.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox's default response to a bare JSON reply is to save rather than display. Chrome will display the JSON as text, and I use the RESTClient extension for Firefox to work with JSON APIs (it allows you to set and inspect additional headers and supply a request body).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install browser extension/plugin. Browsers by default don't support json format.

Comment: Which browser you are using? What version?  It might be coming in package with new browsers.  But browser by default do not support json.  you trying it in IE?

Comment: Added controller code... And I am running this in FireFox.

Comment: Try adding json plugin in Firefox.  It'll work for sure.

Comment: If they don't support it by default, how come I can hit the demo version that spring have running live and get that to display the data?

Their running version : http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting

Comment: Ok. In that case, you need to add header content type as json. You can configure this where you configure request path.

Comment: And i think you also need to add view resolvers like Jackson view resolver in your application.

Comment: I am not fully sure how to do either of these. I guess I need to read up on this stuff.